# Creating XSDs in Bulk

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, xml, xsd

I have about 45 XML data files and I need to create XSDs for them.

I have Visual Studio 2008 installed. What I am doing right now is opening up each XML file and creating the XSD from the menu option and then saving the XSD.

Is there a command line option for me to create all XSDs?

If not, is there a bulk XSD generation tool that can do this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you need to use SqlXml Annotated XSD for Bulkload.